# SQL 'COUNT' function not working

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want an SQL Query to return me the total number of rows. Following is my query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_std  
FROM `student_main` AS sm,
     `student_subjects` AS stds,
     `sub_subjects` AS ss
WHERE stds.`student_id` = sm.`studen. t_id`  
  AND stds.`subs_id` = ss.`subs_id`  
  AND stds.`subs_id` = 1  
  AND sm.`std_postcode` LIKE '%HA02AN%'
GROUP BY stds.`student_id`
```

The query joins three tables:
1)  `student_main` which is the main table and stores student info.
2)  `sub_subjects` which is the main table to store info about subjects/courses
3)  `student_subjects` this table consists of both student_id and subs_id as foreign keys and shows the subjects which the student is taking.

Following is the screen shot of the `student_subjects` table.

[image]

Now when I run the Query, it is supposed to display 3 in the output because a total of 3 students are studying the subject with id 1. but instead the query gives me an output like this:

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: When  you use `group by` then all aggregate functions (like `count()`) apply to EACH group and not the complete resultset

Comment: because of group by . Remove the group by . it will work

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `GROUP BY`.  And learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_std  
FROM `student_main` sm JOIN
     `student_subjects` stds
     ON stds.`student_id` = sm.`studen. t_id` JOIN
     `sub_subjects` ss
     ON stds.`subs_id` = ss.`subs_id`  
WHERE stds.`subs_id` = 1  AND sm.`std_postcode` LIKE '%HA02AN%';
```

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax with an `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have written all my queries with simple joins. I hope it does not make any problem???

Comment: @Ajmal "Simple" joins are effectively deprecated since 1992. That is almost a quarter of a century ago. It's time that you drop the bad habit.

Comment: i will drop it from now on but I have used it in many places in my projects. I hope it don't make any issue.