# SQL query not giving exact result

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to write an SQL Query that should return the total number of tutors who are teaching a specific subject in a specific town.

This is my Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `tutor_main` tm 
  JOIN `tutor_subjects` ts ON tm.`tutor_id` = ts.`tutor_id`
  JOIN `sub_subjects` ss ON ss.`subs_id` = ts.`subs_id`
  JOIN `town` tt ON tm.`town_id` = tt.`town_id`
  JOIN `subject_level` sl ON sl.`sub_level_id` = ts.`sub_level_id`
WHERE ts.`subs_id` = 1
AND tm.`town_id` = 1
```

Here `tutor_main` as the main table which stores `town_id` as foreign key.
`sub_subjects` as the main subjects table and subject_level table stores subject levels. Similarly `tutor_subjects` table stores the keys of tutor_id, subs_id and sub_level_id.

This is the screenshot of `tutor_subjects` table:

[image]

Note that the `town_id` for all tutors is 1.

Now when I run the query, it gives me 8 in the output. The correct output should be 5 because there are 5 tutors who are teaching subject with id 1 and they are all from town with id 1.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you going to write and debug any of your queries yourself or should we start up an invoice to cover the work we are doing for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697095/sql-count-function-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tm.`tutor_id`)
FROM `tutor_main` tm 
  JOIN `tutor_subjects` ts ON tm.`tutor_id` = ts.`tutor_id`
  JOIN `sub_subjects` ss ON ss.`subs_id` = ts.`subs_id`
  JOIN `town` tt ON tm.`town_id` = tt.`town_id`
  JOIN `subject_level` sl ON sl.`sub_level_id` = ts.`sub_level_id`
WHERE ts.`subs_id` = 1
AND tm.`town_id` = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.